# Can't change .top style attribtue in elements of arraylist (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some images in DIV's that i want to give all the same Top value as the first one in the array (so that they are aligned on one line).

I'm having trouble with following code:
(addBorder is called when the div's are clicked on)

```
<div class="DRAGGABLE ui-widget-content ui-draggable" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 120px; height: 60px; top: 10px; left: 10px; position: relative;" onclick="addBorder(event)"> <img id="PMF01" src="/devices/AAU01-010.gif"></img></div>

var selectedDivs = new Array();
function addBorder(e) {
      if ($ctrlBeingpressed == true) {
      e.target.style.border="5px solid green"; // to show they are selected
      selectedDivs.push(e.target);
      }
  }

 function orderTop(){
  for (i=0;i<selectedDivs.length;i++)
    {
    selectedDivs[i].style.top=selectedDivs[0].style.top();
    }
  }

<button type="button" onclick="orderTop()">Top</button>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head> … </head>
    <body style="position: absolute; cursor: auto;" application"="" onkeyup="clearPress()> <div id=" onkeydown="controlCheck(event)">
        <div id="accordion" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:300px;height:900px" role="tablist"> … </div>
        <div id="buttons" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:315px;width:1100px;height:50px;border:2px solid grey"> … </div>
        <div id="canvas" class="DROPPABLE ui-droppable" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:315px;width:1100px;height:850px;border:2px solid grey">
            <div class="DRAGGABLE ui-widget-content ui-draggable" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 120px; height: 60px; top: 156.117px; left: 188.117px; position: relative;" onclick="addBorder(event)">
                <img id="PMF00" src="/devices/AAU01-010.gif" style="border: 5px solid green;"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="DRAGGABLE ui-widget-content ui-draggable" style="border: 1px solid red; width: 120px; height: 60px; top: 10px; left: 10px; position: relative;" onclick="addBorder(event)">
                <img id="PMF01" src="/devices/AAU01-010.gif"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does `selectedDivs` have any values? Do the `div` elements themselves have `position: absolute` or `fixed`? Seeing your HTML would help.

Comment: <div id="canvas" class="DROPPABLE" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:315px;width:1100px;height:850px;border:2px solid grey">
 </div>
 What u mean that selectedDivs has values? they should be filled with the div elements (event.target)

Comment: [FIXED] Instead of using onclick="addBorder(event)" i used onclick="addBorder(this)", making sure that i wasnt change the style of the image, which is what was happening here. (Because the image was in the div, ofcoures it wouldnt move)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`top` is not a function. You cannot call it. Remove the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

When setting a top style, you need to include the units (ems, px, % etc).  Give this line a go:

```
selectedDivs[i].style.top = selectedDivs[0].style.top + 'px';
```